# Installing LAStools in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, lastools

I am trying to install LAStools for QGIS3.4. I installed the plugin, downloaded LAStools and also wine. But if I try to run it for lasview, this is the error I get:

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'lasview' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS' : '', 'COLORING' : 0, 'GUI' : False, 'INPUT_LASLAZ' : '/Users/makju4245/Downloads/LM_Lidar_Clip.laz', 'POINTS' : 5000000, 'SIZE' : 0, 'VERBOSE' : False }

LAStools command line
/Users/makju4245/Downloads/LAStools/bin/lasview -i "/Users/makju4245/Downloads/LM_Lidar_Clip.laz" -points 5000000
LAStools console output
/bin/sh: /Users/makju4245/Downloads/LAStools/bin/lasview: No such file or directory

Execution completed in 0.05 seconds
Results:
{'': None}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'lasview' finished
```

Even though I have folder called: `/Users/makju4245/Downloads/LAStools/bin`. In this folder, I find lasview.exe and lasview_README.txt.

Comment: By the way, I am using Mac.